# cant edit material ui data-table columns (table head) to text-align center (React)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

in this data table i decalre rows and colums only as simple variables so i cant give them style with 'style={{textAlign: center}}' and i tried adding css file but it didnt work on either tr or th when using this material ui table so im not so sure how to do it... this is my code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';

export default function DataTable({data, someColumns}) {

    const columns = someColumns
      

      
    const rows = data;


  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} checkboxSelection />
    </div>
  );
}
```

by default the data in columns is aligned left and not center how can i change it?

EDIT: i've managed to fix it with this css. thanks to fahad

```
.MuiDataGrid-colCellTitle {
    display: block; 
    text-align:center; 
    width: 100%; 
}

.MuiDataGrid-cell {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

which will center both rows and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

In your style.css you can target th and tr by
this property `.MuiDataGrid-colCellTitle`. So to align it in center use this

Style.css

```
 .MuiDataGrid-colCellTitle {
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

After importing things

```
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';
```

Declare your rows and columns data inside the function.

```
export default function DataGridDemo() {
  const columns = [
    Data in columns
  ];

  const rows = [
    Data in rows
  ];
  
  //Apply your styles

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: 400,
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "red",
        textAlign: "center"
      }}
    >
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} checkboxSelection />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code Sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-leaf-izuhd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: this works but why i cant use text align center? using left: 27% like u did is not good for me since every column have different width and text length

Comment: Use this it will work now
.MuiDataGrid-colCellTitle {
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
}

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who comes across this, check out the [implementation of `ColDef` here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/blob/master/packages/grid/_modules_/grid/models/colDef/gridColDef.ts).

The way to do this 'correctly' would be like this:

```
const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
  {
    field: 'status',
    width: 130,
    // these properties can only be 'left' | 'center' | 'right'
    // note that these only set text-align property.
    headerName: 'Status',
    headerAlign: 'center',
    align: 'center',
    renderCell: (params) => {
      return (
          <Chip label={params.value} />
      )
    }
  },
]);
```

If you're rendering anything other than text (like in the example above) it won't center your content. The cells are `display: flex` and `align-items: center` but to center horizontally you need to add a `justify-content` for centered cells:

```
.MuiDataGrid-cellCenter {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

You can do the same for `MuiDataGrid-cellLeft` or `MuiDataGrid-cellRight` if needed.